# php cURL timeout and fail

Tags: php, curl

how do I know if a connection made with cURL has timed out (using the relative option) OR failed in general?
I can only output the response body/headers, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call curl_error or curl_errno after curl_exec.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php